# Mocking firebase user.reload() in flutter test

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, mocking

I'm trying to mock firestore call with a mocked user.
Using https://pub.dev/packages/fake_cloud_firestore and https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_mocks.

but im getting the error:

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'MockUser' has no instance method 'reload' with matching arguments.
> Receiver: Instance of 'MockUser'
> Tried calling: reload()
> Found: reload() => Future

My method:

```
Future<String> getHistory(
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth, FirebaseFirestore firestore) async {
String title = "";
var user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
user.reload();

if (user != null) {
  await firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('history')
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      title = querySnapshot.docs.single.get('title');
    }
  }).catchError((error) => print(error));
}
return title;
```

}

and the test:

```
test("history", () async {
final mockFirestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
HistoryFirebase historyFirebase;
String historyTitle="";

final user = MockUser(
  isAnonymous: false,
  uid: 'someuid',
  email: 'bob@somedomain.com',
  displayName: 'Bob',
);
var mockFirebaseAuth = MockFirebaseAuth(mockUser: user, signedIn: true);

await instance.collection('users').doc('someuid').collection('history').add({
  'title': "Title num.1",
})

await historyFirebase.getHistory(mockFirebaseAuth, mockFirestore).then((value) => historyTitle=value);
expect(historyTitle, "Title num.1");
```

});

Is there any way to mock the user.reload() or to ignore it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the developer of https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_mocks and he implemented the reload () method.

everything works now